# Not displaying average values for users with more than one instance

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I am fairly new to SQL and I am playing around with it. It is fun and interesting and basically I am trying to select the userId and average gametime for each user who has more than one game session. This is my table below:

```
id  | userId |gameTime  |
________________________    
1   |    1   |     10   | 
2   |    2   |     10   |
3   |    3   |     15   |
4   |    1   |     10   |
5   |    2   |     25   |
_________________________


 CREATE TABLE game_session(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  userId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  gameTime DECIMAL NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO game_session VALUES
  (1, 1, 10),
  (2, 2, 10),
  (3, 3, 15),
  (4, 1, 10),
  (5, 2, 25);
```

So I just want to display all instances of userID more than once and its total average time. I don't want to display the count row in the end.

I wrote my script but it isn't displaying the table **WITHOUT THE COUNT(userID)** AND it is showing the userID even for once instance, not more than 1!

This is my script:

```
SELECT userID, AVG(gameTime)
FROM game_session
WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(userID) FROM game_session) > 1)
GROUP BY userID
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Hint:  `HAVING` for filtering on aggregations.

Comment: `WHERE` is for pre-aggregation filtering, while `HAVING` - for post-aggregation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry mate, I'm not quite with you mate. Could you please help me out, would mean a lot

Comment: Gametime looks a lot like an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a `having` clause.

Try this out:

```
select userID, avg(gameTime)
from game_session
group by userID
having count(userID) > 1;
```

Comment: Worked like a CHARM! THANKS MATE. Where was I going wrong? Also what does GROUP BY mean

Comment: You were using `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`. Read more of `GROUP BY` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: Whats the difference between WHERE and HAVING? Also, how comes you didn't have to do SELECT COUNT(userID)?

Comment: You can read more about `HAVING` here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp. You can think of `HAVING` as being used in place of `WHERE` for aggregate functions like `AVG`, `SUM`, etc.